Неразрешённый внешний символ LNK2001
Имеется простой код
Container.h
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container() {};
    void set(T _obj);
private:
    T obj;
};

Container.cpp
#include "Container.h"

template<typename T> 
void Container<T>::set(T _obj)
{
    obj = _obj;
}

main.cpp
#include "Container.h"

int main()
{
    Container<int> c;
    int n = 1;
    c.set(n);
    return 1;
}

И вылетает ошибка

main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void
__cdecl Container::set(int)" (?set@?$Container@H@@QEAAXH@Z).

Всё делалось в visual studio, файлы создавались там же.

возможные дубликаты
